# mysql n:m relationship delete query 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, relationship, sql-delete, nm, mysql-error-1242

I have two SQL Tables, 'products' and 'tags'. They have an n:m relationship, using a third table 'product_tags'.

I want to delete some products and corresponding tags all together.

Let's say, I have products.product_id=3, that product have tags.tag_id=3, tags.tag_id=5

product_tags table

product_id 3 tag_id 3 
product_id 3 tag_id 5

```
delete from tags where tag_id in (select product_tags.tag_id from product_tags where product_id =3);
delete from tags where tag_in = any (select product_tags.tag_id from product_tags where product_id=3);
```

either will produce

```
0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

So, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all** you most likely want to delete tags that are not used with other products. E.g. if a tag with `tag_id = 3` is also used with some other product let's say `product_id = 1` then you shouldn't delete this tag.

**Secondly** if you have proper parent-child relationships enforced with foreign keys you have to delete rows from tables in proper sequence. First you should delete rows from `product_tags`.

That being said your code to safely delete a product along with unused tags might look

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_product(IN _product_id INT)
BEGIN
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tags_to_be_deleted;

  START TRANSACTION;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tags_to_be_deleted(tag_id INT PRIMARY KEY);
  INSERT INTO tmp_tags_to_be_deleted
  SELECT tag_id
    FROM product_tags t
   WHERE product_id = _product_id
     AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT *
      FROM product_tags
     WHERE tag_id = t.tag_id
       AND product_id <> t.product_id
  );

  DELETE 
    FROM product_tags
   WHERE product_id = _product_id;

  DELETE t
    FROM tags t JOIN tmp_tags_to_be_deleted x
      ON t.tag_id = x.tag_id;

  DELETE 
    FROM products
   WHERE product_id = _product_id;

  COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
CALL delete_product(3);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/408ad/1)** demo

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thank you for having your time!! I will try your solution~. Have a GREAT day~!